All real solutions of trigonometric equation

Find all real number $a$ ($0\le a<2\pi$), such that there exists two real numbers $b,c$ satisfying the following three conditions:


$a<b<c<2\pi$
$2b=a+c$
$2\cos(a)=\cos(b)+\cos(c)$

What I’ve tried:
Let $d=b-a$, then we can write $b=a+d$, $c=a+2d$ and $0<d<\pi-a/2$, then the above conditions are equivalent to $\cos(a+d)+\cos(a+2d)=2\cos(a)$.
Let $f(d)=\cos(a+d)+\cos(a+2d)$, then it's equivalent to $2\cos(a)$ being in the range of $f$ on $(0,\pi-a/2)$.
When $a$ is no less than $\pi$, $f'>0$, so $f$ is strictly increasing, which can't satisfy the condition. So $0\le a<\pi$.
If $f$ is strictly decreasing and then strictly increasing, the condition reduces to $1-\cos(a/2)>2\cos(a)$, which gives the answer. But I couldn't figure out how to prove the monotonicity of $f$.

To solve the problem, we do not actually need to know the monotonicity of $f$ for all cases of $d$.
If $d\in(0,\frac{\pi-a}{2}]$ or $d\in[\pi-a,\pi-\frac{a}{2})$, it is easy to show that $f$ is strictly decreasing and strictly increasing respectively by calculating $f'$.
For $d\in(\frac{\pi-a}{2},\pi-a)$, it is not easy to know the monotonicity of $f$, but we do not have to. In this case, $0\le a<a+d<\pi$, $\pi<a+2d<2\pi-a$, thus $\cos(a)>\cos(a+d)$, $\cos(a)>\cos(a+2d)$, adding two together we get $2\cos(a)>f(d)$, which excludes the case for the answer.
Therefore the original problem is solved.
